# delete all rows associated with sql query

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with 5 columns (primary_key, abstractid, sentid, wordid, term).

This query pulls up a list of distinct terms that appear in less than 6 distinct abstractid's.

```
SELECT 
    term, COUNT(distinct abstractid) AS "num" 
FROM 
    nsfabstracts 
HAVING 
   COUNT(distinct abstractid) < 6 
GROUP BY 
   term 
ORDER BY 
   "num" DESC;
```

How would I modify the above query to count the number of rows it returns instead? Also, how would I delete all rows associated with the above query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How can you have HAVING before GROUP BY?

Comment: I'm not sure. using the query I listed above I appear to get the expected results. I'll try reordering and see if I get the same results. I added a tag for oracle-sqldeveloper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be lazy, use a sub-select:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (
     SELECT term, COUNT(distinct abstractid) AS "num" FROM nsfabstracts HAVING COUNT(distinct abstractid) < 6 GROUP BY term
)
```

and

```
DELETE FROM nsfabstracts WHERE term in (
     SELECT term, COUNT(distinct abstractid) AS "num" FROM nsfabstracts HAVING COUNT(distinct abstractid) < 6 GROUP BY term
)
```

Comment: This actually isn't lazy in my opinion, and you have the benefit of running the sub-select to verify the rows which will be deleted before actually doing so (if running the command interactively).